# How to create dynamic breadcrumb for a team?

Tags: react-native, breadcrumbs

I'm creating a dynamic breadcrumb for team members in my app using react native. But I cannot find a good example or tutorial for it. My team structure is as below:

- User A has 2 members in his team: B, C
- User B has 2 members in his team: D, E
- User D has 3 members in his team: F, G, H

When I go to "view members" of D, I want to show a dynamic breadcrumb at the top of the page like so: `A > B > D`.

Each user has a different number of members, so I have difficulties in creating the dynamic breadcrumb.

Are there any ideas, examples or suggestions for this case?

Comment: How are your team objects structured?